# linq query one to one

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

trying to get the concert name, date and venue (which is stored on another table)
but it doesn't seem to be working, but it keeps pulling back null.

```
var test = from f in db.Concert
           where f.Name.StartsWith(concertName)
           select new
           {
               f.Name,
               f.StartDateTime,
               venues = from v in db.Venues
                        where v.ID == f.VenueID
                        select v.Address
           }
```

Edit:

The relationship between Venue and Concert is that Concert has a VenueID that relates to the Venue ID.  I need to pass a string back. something like

```
foreach (var e in test)
{
   html += "<div> e.Name +":" + e.Address </div>;
}
```

Comment: You should use navigation properties.  (`f.Venue.Address`)

Comment: Is it `StartsWith` or `Contains`?

Comment: Is there any need for .ToString() ?, also is there any type of realtionship in your model between venues and concerts tables ? provide more info.

Comment: oh right, no need for the ToString().  venues and concerts have a relationship. venue is just a venue, but concert has a FK venueID that matches with venue ID

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use group join to get all Venues related to Concert

```
var test = from f in db.Concert
           join v in db.Venues on f.VenueID equals v.ID into g
           where f.Name.StartsWith(concertName)
           select new
           {
               f.Name,
               f.StartDateTime,
               Venues = g.Select(x => x.Address)
           };
```

Usage of results:

```
foreach (var e in test)
{
   // e.Name
   // e.StartDateTime

   foreach(var address in e.Venues)
      // address
}
```

Comment: just had to change the Venues = g.Select(x => v.Address) to Venues = g.Select(x => x.Address)
This is working great. its a 1:1 relationship so I don't think I will need the second foreach.  Thanks!

Comment: @datatest thanks! And sorry for typo, sure it should be `x.Address`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it's safe to assume a 1:1 relationship between Concerts and Venues.  Given that, you can use `join` instead.

```
var test = from f in db.Concert
           join v in db.Venues on v.ID equals f.VenueID
           where f.Name.StartsWith(concertName)
           select new
           {
               f.Name,
               f.StartDateTime,
               v.Address
           };
```

Comment: you are correct abot the 1:1 relationship. though when trying your code I am getting cannot resolve name, on the v and f...

Answer (score 0):

If you have a foreign key relationship set up, You don't need to manually query for venues.  In that case you get the venues using `f.Venue`.

Comment: well I can do f.Venue, I can't do f.Venue.Address. and not sure how to get the Address